# call a J2EE Java method after WAS restarted

Tags: jakarta-ee, was

We are using WAS server and we want to call a J2EE method after WAS started. Is there any way that we can invoke a method? Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Subbarao

Comment: You may be looking for the [@StartupBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) annotation. Its use is somewhat documented in [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html), but I didn't find much documentation otherwise. Note that the method won't be called after your app server is started but rather while your application is launched, which I assumed might be the same to you.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for your reply. We have few schedulers that we want to start in server once the server is up and running. So it is not at the point of application launched instead we want to invoke when server started/restarted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WAS so I might be missing a specific solution, but I think adding an EJB jar to your app server, making sure it is deployed at the server start as the first module and using startup bean to run code near the server startup would be a common solution. I've searched a bit for other solutions but the only thing I found is a [startup service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/startupservice/package-summary.html) which handles StartupBean from modules and apps.